# What is the probability that Tom's finding $22$ of the end of the process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Tom's calculator , when $3$ is being pressed

- $3$ with probability $\frac {1}{6}$
- $4$ with probability $\frac {1}{3}$
- $6$ with probability $\frac {1}{2}$

Perceives them as seen above.

Tom will do the process with this calculator that only $3$ is broken

$$23 -\biggr(\frac{12}{3}\biggr)$$

According to this, What is the probability that Tom's finding $22$ of the end of the process?

Comment: Some of the time he will successfully type $23-(\frac{12}{3})$.  Other times he will accidentally type $2\color{red}{2}-(\frac{12}{3})$, other times still he'll type $23-(\frac{12}{\color{red}{6}})$, or $2\color{red}{2}-(\frac{12}{\color{red}{6}})$ etc... find the probability of each specific occurrence and sum up those that correspond to a final value of $22$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I did not misunderstood your question, there are $3$ method that will get $22$.

$23-1, 24-2, 26-4$

So, we start of with fraction part of the question. You will never get $1.
\frac {12}{6}=2$ which satisfy $24-2$ and $\frac {12}{3}=4$, Which satisfy $26-4$. $2$ ways to obtain $22$.

Since there are $3\times3$ possible events.

Chances of obtaining through $\frac {12}{6}$ is $(\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{2})$

Chances of obtaining through $\frac{12}{3}$ is $(\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{6})$

sums up to be $0.25$, $25$% Chance of getting.

Hope I did not mistaken your question.
Good luck!

**Notice:** Edited after Ross Millikan mentioned what I did wrong.

Comment: Not all the events are equally probable, so $2/9$ is not correct.

Comment: That's a good point i missed out ! Thanks

Comment: Check the new edit and didn't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

There are nine possible events, three for each time three is pressed.  Compute which of the nine result in $22$.  Then compute the chance of each of those and add them up.